# The kernel and image for some maps are isomorphic for two two groups. Does it mean that the groups are isomorphic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups

Let $G$ and $H$ be finite abelian groups (written additively) such that $|G|=|H|$. For a prime $p$ define the map $\phi_p:G\rightarrow G$ as 
$$\phi_p(x)=px$$
Similarly we can define $\phi_p:H\rightarrow H$.

Assume that for every prime $p$ dividing $|G|$, we have $\phi_p(G)\cong \phi_p(H)$ and $\ker \phi_p\cong \ker \phi_p$.

Does it mean that $G\cong H$?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it does mean that. Take $p$ to be a prime that does not divide neither the order of $G$ nor the order of $H$. Then $\phi_p$ (you really should use different symbols for the maps $G\to G$ and $H\to H$, like $\phi_p$ and $\psi_p$) is an automorphism for both $G$ and $H$.

**Edit** Let
$$
G\simeq\Bbb Z_{p_1^{e_1}}\times \cdots\Bbb Z_{p_n^{e_n}}
$$be a representation of $G$ as a product of cyclic groups, each the order of some power of a prime (by the structure theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, this representation is unique except for the order of the factors). Then the kernel of $\phi_p$ is isomorphic to $\Bbb Z_p^k$ where $k$ is the number of $p_i$ which are equal to $p$. The image is isomorphic to 
$$
\Bbb Z_{p_1^{f_1}}\times \cdots\Bbb Z_{p_n^{f_n}}
$$where $f_i=e_i$ if $p\neq p_i$, and $f_i=e_i-1$ if $p=p_i$.

From this we see that we can reconstruct $G$ uniquely (up to isomorphism) from the kernel and image of $\phi_p$: take the image of $\phi_p$, and for each factor of the form $\Bbb Z_{p^f}$, increase the exponent by $1$. Let $m$ be $\log_p(|\ker \phi_p|)$ minus the number of exponents you increased this way. Take the group you have made, and multiply it by $\Bbb Z_p^{m}$ and the resulting group is isomorphic to $G$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out this trivial case, I had missed it. I have edited the question.

Comment: @learning_math I added a proof in the non-trivial case. It's enough that they are isomorphic for a single $p$, although if there are more than one prime available (i.e. the order of the group isn't the power of a single prime) you don't even have to mention kernels or reconstruct anything. Is enough that the parts of the groups that aren't changed by the two different $\phi_p$ together cover the whole group.